# Where should I put a zip file holding source code that shows how to reproduce a bug?

Tags: discussion

Have a zip file containing a source code that reproduces a bug.  Does Stack Overflow have a place meant for hosting such files or is there some place in particular I should upload the code to?

Comment: If you need a zip file to contain all the code, you are doing it wrong: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @patricksweeney - I understand what you mean, maybe I should have said that It only has the files required to execute the program which shows the bug

Comment: Even then, that's waaayyyyy too much code.